# Apache Oozie throws classnotfound exception while creating mysql DB

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera, oozie

I am trying to use mysql DB with apache OOzie.
my $OOZIE_HOME is 
-bash: /opt/oozie_install/oozie-3.3.0-cdh4.2.2: Is a directory

But I copied mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar in almost every possible places.
Like I copied it inside

```
/opt/oozie_install/oozie-3.3.0-cdh4.2.2
/opt/oozie_install/oozie-3.3.0-cdh4.2.2/libs
/opt/oozie_install/oozie-3.3.0-cdh4.2.2/libtools
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/libs
/user/home/hadoop/
```

But I am still getting ClassnotFoundException.

```
java.lang.Exception: Could not connect to the database: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.validateConnection(OozieDBCLI.java:473)
        at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.createDB(OozieDBCLI.java:179)
        at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.run(OozieDBCLI.java:118)
        at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.main(OozieDBCLI.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.createConnection(OozieDBCLI.java:462)
        at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.validateConnection(OozieDBCLI.java:469)
```

**Exactly where am I supposed to copy the Mysql connector.**

I have verified my oozie-site.xml-
[image]

I followed the following steps to use mysql in Oozie

[image]

My oozie directory looks like-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy `mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar` to `/opt/oozie_install/oozie-3.3.0-cdh4.2.2/libext` directory then restart oozie instance. Make sure that mysql user oozie has suffient privileges to the database oozie, if not, grant suffient permission using grant command in mysql server.

Comment: thanks but I have no directory name libext , I have uploaded my dir extensions inside oozie-3.3.0-cdh4.2.2.

Comment: Create that directory if missing and try it

Answer (score 0):

i meet the same problem finally i solve it by edit the oozie-env.sh and append the JAVA_HOME at last export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7   the java_home is yourself javapath

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I was converting my local Derby instance to MySql.  The difference between my issue and the others, is that I did not install an RPM.  My Oozie instance was pre-compiled in a tar.gz file.  I had to copy the mysql-connector-java-bin.jar to the oozie-server/lib directory.  This was in addition to copying it to the lib, libext, and libtools directories.  I am not sure if all of those are needed, but I do know that oozie-server/lib is needed for Oozie to start.  Hope this helps someone!